# Access Caption property alternative for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have searched for an answer to this question everywhere. There is [one](https://forums.asp.net/t/1113376.aspx?Equivalent%20of%20MS%20Access%20Captions%20in%20SQL%20Server%20) forum asking the same question but the solution given does not work. Alias and Caption is not the same thing. In MS Access you can set alias with SQL using:

```
([Field1]+[Field2]) as expr1
```

However, in query design view you can change the caption property of `expr1` to something like `salary`. This will change the field name in datasheet view but does not change the alias, which means fields in reports or forms depending on this query does not have to be modified from `expr1` to `salary`. The `salary` column will only appear in the datasheet view of the query.

I cannot find a way to do the same in SQL Server. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use Datasheet Caption property of form's field? Also you can just change a caption of the label associated with form's field

Comment: The reason I cannot do that is because I am using linked tables and I cannot modify anything at all in Access design view. All changes need to come from SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Caption` property to linked table(linked view) in Access's `TableDef`

If there is no caption yet

```
Dim p As Property
Dim tbl As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim Db As Database
Set Db = CurrentDb

Set tbl = Db.TableDefs("LINKED TABLE NAME")
Set fld = tbl.fields("FIELD NAME")
Set p = fld.CreateProperty("Caption", dbText, "CAPTION FOR FIELD")
fld.Properties.Append p
fld.Properties.Refresh
```

If there is caption and you want to change it

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("LINKED TABLE NAME").fields("FIELD NAME").Properties("Caption").Value = "CAPTION FOR FIELD"
```

Or by GIU way: open linked table in design mode, go to field definition, print disired caption to `Caption` property, press `save` button